# How do I "bounce" (redirect) an email in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

PINE has a nice "bounce" command which allows the user to re-send a received email in otherwise unmodified form to a new email address.

How do I do this in Thunderbird (version 3.1.7)?

Comment: All professionnal E-mail clients provide such a function to report errors or spam with the original headers. For example `mutt` is providing it.

Answer (score 10):

There's a plug-in for doing this. Haven't tried it personally, but here it is:

http://mailredirect.mozdev.org/index.html

> "The mailredirect extension for Mozilla Thunderbird (version 0.7 and above) and Mozilla Mail client adds ability to redirect one or more mails to one or more recipients.
>
> *Feature of mail redirecting is also known as bouncing.*"

Comment: The version on addons.mozilla.org is obsolete, it should be installed from this page: http://mailredirect.mozdev.org/installation.html

Comment: There are two places to download the 'Mail Redirect' plugin from: 1. https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/thunderbird/addon/mailredirect/ -> the official plugins site, accessible through the addons interface within Thunderbird. 2. http://mailredirect.sourceforge.net/installation.html -> the source site maintained by the developers. As of version 0.8.4, they are in sync. Installing through the interface is more convenient, but technically it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the add on `Mail Redirect`:

[image: Mail Redirect 0.9.5]

Tested and approved on Thunderbird 45.8.0, 52.7.0.